# How to call onEnter function on Route in React Router Multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-router

router 2.0. I have my route setup like this.

```
 <Route path='/' component={app}>
    <IndexRoute component={require('./dashboard')}  onEnter={logger.log} />
    <Route path='signup' component={require('./signup')}  onEnter={logger.log} />
    <Route path='login' component={require('./login')}  onEnter={logger.log} />
</Route>
```

As you can see I am doing onEnter={logger.log} multiple times which is redudant.

I tried putting onEnter handler on root route of app but it called that handler function only once. It doesn't get called for ex when I navigate from login to signup.

Is there any way that I declare onEnter of all routes to call logger.log only once so that I don't have to repeat the same again and again.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [OnChange](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onchangeprevstate-nextstate-replace-callback) hook on the root Route

`onChange(prevState, nextState, replace, callback?)`

*Called on routes when the location changes, but the route itself neither enters or leaves. For example, this will be called when a route's children change, or when the location query changes. It provides the previous router state, the next router state, and a function to redirect to another path. `this` will be the route instance that triggered the hook.
If `callback` is listed as a 4th argument, this hook will run asynchronously, and the transition will block until `callback` is called.*

like so

```
 <Route path='/' component={app} onChange={logger.log} >
    <IndexRoute component={require('./dashboard')} />
    <Route path='signup' component={require('./signup')} />
    <Route path='login' component={require('./login')} />
</Route>
```

note that the signature is different so you'd have to make sure logger.log grabs the necessary data from `nextState` in this case.